# Distribution of $Y(t)=B(t)$ when $\max\limits_{0\le s \le t}B(s)<a$ and $Y(t)=a$ otherwise

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

> If $B(t),t\ge0$ is a standard Brownian motion with initial condition $B(0)=0$ and $a>0$, let $Y(t)=B(t)$ when $\max\limits_{0\le s \le t}B(s)<a$ and $Y(t)=a$ otherwise. 
>   Find the distribution function of $Y(t)$.

Let $M(t)=maxB(s)$.

Here I am confused if the question is asking me to find $F_Y(t)=P\{Y(t)\le y\}$ or $F_Y(t)=P\{Y(t)=B(t)|M(t)<a\}$ or  $F_Y(t)=P\{M(t)<a|Y(t)=B(t)\}$ or something else related to Bayes equation.

Comment: You are supposed to determine $F_{Y(t)}(y)=P\{Y(t)\le y\}$ for every $y$ and every $t$ (note the typo in your post), or any other characterization of the *distribution* of $Y(t)$, for each fixed $t$. In principle, you could also be asked for the distribution of *the whole process* $(Y(t))_{t\geqslant0}$ but I doubt that.

Comment: @Did is Y(t) a homogeneous Markov process?

Comment: Obviously no, since $P(Y(t)=a)$ is an increasing function of $t$.

Comment: @Did But $Y(0)=0$ and $Y(t)$ is an independent increment process (there is a lemma that says a Stochastic Process with independent increment process is a Markov process), therefore, it should be a homogeneous Markov process.

Comment: Markov? Yes. Homogeneous? No.

Comment: @Did Why the homogeneity of a Markov process is related to probability being an increasing function? Isn't this process a stationary increment process?

Comment: Let us be quite specific. If homogeneity of the process means stationarity of its increments, then this process is indeed homogeneous. But if homogeneity means stationarity, then this process is not stationary since the distribution of $Y(t)$ depends on $t$.

Comment: Re the distribution of each $Y(t)$, note that the joint distribution of $(B(t),M(t))$ is explicitely known, from which the distribution of $Y(t)=g(B(t),M(t))$ with $g(b,m)=b\mathbf 1_{m<a}+a\mathbf 1_{m\geqslant a}$, follows.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the stopping time $T=\inf\lbrace t\geq 0 | B_t=a \rbrace$. Now find out how this stopping time is related to $\max_{0\leq s\leq t} B_s$ and write $Y_t$ as a stopped process. You are asked to determine the distribution of this stopped process I think.

Comment: well, thanks for making it a little bit more clear, but still I don't know how and which one of the definitions I have given is right?!

Comment: If I remember correctly you can use the martingale property of $B_t$ to determinte the distribution of $T$. Then note that $P(\max_{0\leq s\leq t} B_s \leq a)=P(T \leq t)$. Now $P(Y_t\leq y)=P(B_t \leq y| T\leq t)+P(a \leq y|T> t)$.
Long story short your first suggestion is probably right.

Comment: What I meant earlier btw is that $Y_t=B_{(t\wedge T)}$.

Comment: I don't know why somebody has given you a downvote while in fact, I think what you are saying can help me to lead an answer. So, the following is what I need to calculate: let $M(t)=\max\limits_{0\le s \le t}B(s)<a$ then we have $F_Y(t)=P(Y_t\leq y)=P\{B(t)\le y|M(t)<a\}+P\{a\le y|M(t)\ge a\}$

Comment: How to calculate that? :-\